# Removing Comments with Perl

Tags: regex, perl

Is there any regular expression that is able to remove all comments of the // and /**/ variety from a given C program say in perl?

Given the multi-line program, it should use the regular expression to remove the comments and return the non-commented out portion.

Thanks.

Comment: In general case, you should use a parser, since you need to recognize whether /* is part of string or not.

Comment: Test case of how a general case may look like. I am not sure if it has covered all tricky cases, but the cases in the file are already quite tricky: http://pastebin.com/gcP2xjgR . As you can see, it trips the syntax highlighter of pastebin already.

Comment: @nhahtdh, You only need a tokenizer, not a parser.

Answer (score 7):

Try with [`Regexp::Common::comment`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Regexp-Common/lib/Regexp/Common/comment.pm):

```
  use Regexp::Common qw /comment/;
  while (<>) {
        s/($RE{comment}{C++})//;
  }
```

Comment: Wow, interesting module. How it do manage multiline comments?

Comment: I don't know, haven't tried it yet, but, given that the author is Damian Conway, I assume it handles them ok. The only requirement would probably be to treat the c++ source file as a whole, not line by line

Comment: s/($RE{comment}{'C++'})//;

Answer (score 6):

It's a [FAQ](http://faq.perl.org):

[How do I use a regular expression to strip C-style comments from a file?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file?)